# Azure Devops Predefined Variables - pass as parameter

Tags: npm, azure-devops, cypress

I am using an NPM run task in Azure Devops Pipelines. I would like to pass an Azure Predefined Variable into my package.json.

eg: npm run cypresstask

So that I can then pass this as a parameter for 'cypress run --ci-build-id '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

NPM Run Task command:
run cypress:ci --azbuildid=$(Build.BuildNumber)

then within package.json you can provide it as
cypress run --ci-build-id $npm_config_azbuildid

So you set params with the --. Provide predefined variables using $() and access them within package.json using $npm_config_

Comment: Hi @Steven,

Thanks a lot for sharing your experience and the answer.
I recommend that you can mark yourself answer as the solution of this topic. This maybe very helpful to the people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` file you can write your commands inside scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress run --ci-build-id"
  }
```

And in your yml file you can just use:

```
npm test
```